# Does there exist something like std::tie for std::pair?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, std-pair

Eg with tuples:

```
#include <tuple>        // std::tuple, std::make_tuple, std::tie

int num;
char letter;
std::tuple<int,char> num_letter;

num_letter = std::make_tuple(10, 'a');
std::tie(num, letter) = num_letter;  // unpack num_letter into num and letter
```

Is there something equivalent with pairs?

```
// ...
num_letter = std::make_pair(10, 'a');
std::pair_tie(num, letter) = num_letter;
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Actually, the code for pairs is exactly the same, since `std::tuple` has [`operator =` with `std::pair` as an argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator%3D).

```
num_letter = std::make_pair(10, 'a');
std::tie(num, letter) = num_letter;
```

Comment: @wrhall this proves you should at least try the most obvious one :)

Comment: I was looking at someone else's code, and they were iterating through the elements of a map; I was hopeful that someone would show me something like tie but slightly different that would have made sense to use in that case.

I'm not convinced tie is really a readability improvement here, and they were grabbing const references. So it doesn't quite work.

The question was more exploratory than anything.

Comment: Nice. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work the other way around `num_letter = std::tie(num, letter)` (no conversion from `tuple<...>` to `pair<...>`).